# Why does my h3 get added inside an li tag in wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I have sidebar and when I add the components to it, the heading get added inside the li items of ul, making it look ugly. How do I overcome this. Unfortunately I have little or no knowledge of both wordpress and php.

here is how I get it in firebug:

```
<li class="widget widget_categories" id="categories-8"><h2 class="widgettitle">Categories</h2>
        <ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a title="View all posts filed under Uncategorized" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/?cat=1">Uncategorized</a>
</li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

This is what I have in sidebar apart from some static html ul li pieces:

```
<?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar() ) : else : ?>
        <ul class="ul-cat">

        <?php wp_list_categories('show_count=1&title_li='); ?> 




        <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?> 
</ul>       
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What do you want to do with your h3 tags, it's generated automatically by WordPress function `register_sidebar` inside functions.php though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To use **wp_list_categories** and **wp_get_archives** inside your sidebar.php you can follow 
>   [**wp_list_categories**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) and [**wp_get_archives**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_get_archives).

If your theme supports dynamic sidebar then you can remove `wp_list_categories` and `wp_get_archives` function calls from your sidebar.php and can use dynamic widgets from WordPress admin > Appearance > widgets and add `Categories` and `Archives` widgets to your sidebar.
This is only an example, basically resides inside `functions.php`, generates dynamic widgets

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</li>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>'
));
```

If you leave `before_title` and `after_title` blank as follows

```
'before_title' => '',
'after_title' => ''
```

Then your `h2` will be gone.

**Note:** In your question you mentioned `h3` but in your generated HTML code I saw `h2`.

Comment: I need on the sidebar a static widget, that should pull the list of latest songs or something like that, as this doesn't come under dynamic widgets, can you help me how to do that.

Comment: thank you for the answer, though you didnt reply to my coment